# adChar and adParamInput is not recognized

Tags: vbscript

I'm doing a sql to oracle migration. I have to change a lot of old vbscript code.
This is an example of the new code that I'm using with Oracle.
And this is the bit of code that's causing problems,

```
cmd.CreateParameter("v_CdEnt", adChar, adParamInput, 4, Request("ENTIDADE"))
```

For some reason, I get an error because of adChar and adParamInput. If i use

```
cmd.CreateParameter("v_CdEnt", 129 , 1 , 4, Request("ENTIDADE"))
```

using the value of the constant, everything works fine.
Any ideas??

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
                            Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

                            With cmd
                                .ActiveConnection   = GlobaloConn
                                .CommandText        = "GetBalcoes"
                                .CommandType        = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
                                .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("v_CdEnt", adChar, adParamInput, 4, Request("ENTIDADE"))
                            End With

                            Set oRS = cmd.Execute  

                            do while not oRS.Eof 
                                If oRS.Fields(1) = Request("BALCAO") then
                                    %><option value="<%=oRS.Fields(1)%>" selected="selected"><%=left(oRS.Fields(2), 30)  & "-" & oRS.Fields(1)%></option>
                                    <%
                                Else
                                    %><option value="<%=oRS.Fields(1)%>"><%=left(oRS.Fields(2), 30)  & "-" & oRS.Fields(1)%></option>
                                    <%
                                End If
                                oRS.MoveNext
                            loop

                            oRS.Close

                            Set oRS  = nothing
                            Set cmd  = nothing
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VBScript does not know about the ad* constants of ADODB. BTW, the same holds for the xls* or wd* constants of Excel or Word.

For ad* constants you can:

1. just use numbers (with comments; e.g. `.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc`)
2. define them yourself (e.g. `Const adCmdStoredProc = 4`)
3. include (an edited version of) [adovbs.inc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yep, that's what I found out in the meantime. I used option 1. It's working. tks.