# CreateParameter in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ado

I am getting error while executing following code. Below is the code

```
oConn.Open strConnectionString, strUserName, strPassword
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
'Create and populate the paramaters collection
With objCommand
  .ActiveConnection = oConn
  .CommandText = "my sp"
  .CommandType = 4
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("my parameter", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "my value")
  Set objRecordset = .Execute
End With
```

Error is occured while adding parameter.

Comment: What is the error? Is there a message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In plain VBScript the ad* constants are not defined. Evidence:

```
>> Set c = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
>> c.CreateParameter "my parameter", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "my value"
>>
Error Number:       3001
Error Description:  Die Argumente sind vom falschen Typ, liegen außerhalb des Gültigkeitsbereiches oder sind miteinander unvereinbar.
>> adVarChar = 200
>> adParamInput = 1
>> c.CreateParameter "my parameter", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "my value"
>>
>> (No news are good news)
```

So define them.

[see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19162178/603855)

Comment: What is stopping you from flagging this as a duplicate? You even point to the duplicate answer in this answer...